# PySide2 and pyinstaller gui application won't run on certain windows computers

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside, pyinstaller, pyside2

I have built a small gui application using PySide2 as my gui framework and PyInstaller to make a one file exe file.

The application works perfectly on some PCs (both Windows 7 and 10), however, on a few other PCs it won't launch - showing me the error message:

'Fatal error!: Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins'

I believe that it may not be bundling the Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Core.dll and Qt5Widgets.dll, however I do not know how to do this with PyInstaller.

Does anyone know how one would fix this?

Here is my .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Application',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , icon='Images\\Application_icon.ico')
```

**Edit**

Here is the full output when run from cmd and debug=True. One thing I found odd was it referring to the PC I developed the application on (e.g. `File "c:\users\jake\Projects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInsta
ller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module`), instead of the PC I was testing on and got this error message from.

```
[4588] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[4588] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\User\Desktop\Application.exe
[4588] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\User\Desktop
[4588] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[4588] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\User\Desktop\Application.exe
[4588] LOADER: Extracting binaries
[4588] LOADER: Executing self as child
[4588] LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882
[4588] LOADER: Setting up to run child
[4588] LOADER: Creating child process
[4588] LOADER: Waiting for child process to finish...
[4752] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[4752] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\User\Desktop\Application.exe
[4752] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\User\Desktop
[4752] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882
[4752] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\User\Desktop\Application.exe
[4752] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882)
[4752] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[4752] LOADER: manifestpath: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882\Application.exe.manifest
[4752] LOADER: Activation context created
[4752] LOADER: Activation context activated
[4752] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882\py
thon36.dll
[4752] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[4752] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[4752] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI458
82\base_library.zip;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882
[4752] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882
[4752] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[4752] LOADER: Bootloader option: pyi-windows-manifest-filename Folder Hatcher.e
xe.manifest
[4752] LOADER: Initializing python
[4752] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[4752] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45
882\base_library.zip;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45882
[4752] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[4752] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[4752] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[4752] LOADER: extracted struct
[4752] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[4752] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[4752] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[4752] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[4752] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[4752] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[4752] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[4752] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[4752] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[4752] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[4752] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 47
, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jake\Projects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInsta
ller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 712, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrappe
r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 49
, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jake\Projects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInsta
ller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.: PySide2.
QtCore
[4752] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins
[4752] LOADER: OK.
[4752] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
[4588] LOADER: Back to parent (RC: -1)
[4588] LOADER: Doing cleanup
[4588] LOADER: Freeing archive status for C:\Users\User\Desktop\Application.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue (app running well on some, but not all Win clients) with a PySide2 app build with the following packages:

- pyinstaller==3.14
- PySide2==5.12.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 47, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed:
```

The Problem was solved (on some clients) by installing the Visual C++2015 Redistribution Package (x86) on the Windows 10 clients: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840

Yet I consider this issue still work in progress...

Answer (score 1):

I remember using this before http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files

maybe it will sort you out.

Anyway i'm no windows expert but with linux builds the binary created works only on boxes/machines that have the very same distro and architecture of the building one